# Why $ 0^{\infty} $ isn't indeterminate form?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I was trying to calculate $$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} x^{\frac{1}{x}}
$$ I know left hand limit is not equal to right hand limit, hence limit doesn't exist. But I was trying to get their values as well. Then I came to the question why $ 0^{\infty} $ isn't an indeterminate form ?

Comment: An expression being an indeterminate form does not mean the limit does not exist. In fact, the right limit of $x^{1/x}$ is $0$ and the left limit is undefined in $\mathbb{R}$ (what is $(-1/\pi)^{-\pi}$?)

Comment: The function isn't even defined for $x<0.$ Wat is $(-2/3)^{-3/2}?$

Comment: Limits of kind $(+0)^{+\infty}=0$, $(+0)^{-\infty}=+\infty$. Both forms are not indeterminate.

Comment: The left side limit is not just undefined, the function is undefined on the left side. There is nothing to take the limit of. The left side is not a place where the function is defined,.. Usually, when we say the "limit does not exist" it is because there is something to take the limit of. There isn't here.

Comment: In particular, since the function to the left is not defined, it is not of the "form" $0^\infty,$ and thus this doesn't contradict the statement that $0^\infty$ is determinate.

Answer (score 3):

The left hand limit does not exist because the function is not defined on the left side. So the right side limit is of the "form" $0^\infty,$ but the left side limit is not.

So this does not prove that $0^\infty$ is indeterminate.

As a general rule, we might say $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt x=0,$ but the danger is a case like $\lim_{x\to a}\sqrt{f(x)},$ where we don't know where $f(x)$ is positive or negative. It gets very complicated to define something like: $$\lim_{x\to0}x\sqrt{\sin\frac1x}$$ where there are undefined values all around $0.$

In general, if $X$ is the **domain** of a function - the set of values $x$ where $f(x)$ is defined - we restrict the definition of limit to be only for $x$ in the domain. But for $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ to be defined, we need to require that $a$ is a "limit point" of the set $X.$

For example, talking about $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{x-1}$ is meaningless, because the function isn't defined when $|x|<1.$

Indeed, the "right side" limit of a function, often written $x\to a^+,$ can be thought of as asking what the limit is if we restrict the function to the domain $X=\{x\mid x>a\},$ and similar for left side limits and $X=\{x\mid x<a\}.$

Answer (score 1):

The base eventually becomes less than 1 so when you raise it to a high power it becomes even closer to 0, so the limit is 0. So there is no ambiguity with the limits that calls for indeterminate forms.

More precisely, let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions, and suppose that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=\infty$. Also assume that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. I claim that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)^{g(x)}=0$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and assume that $\epsilon <1$. We need to show that there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)^{g(x)}|< \epsilon$. There is some $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $x \in (c-\delta_1,c+\delta_1)$, $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ and there is some $\delta_2>0$ such that for all $x \in (c-\delta_2,c+\delta_2)$, $g(x)>2$. Now let $\delta<\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. When $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$, $|f(x)^{g(x)}|=|f(x)|^{g(x)}<\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$.This shows that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)^{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: You need $f$ to be a positive function for $f(x)^{g(x)}$ to be defined, which is the source of the  OP is having, OP wonders why the limits from both sides don't agree when $0^\infty$ is, they are told, not an indeterminate form. The problem is that there is no function on  left.

Comment: I added the condition. Anyway, my post answers the question of why $0^\infty$ isn't an indeterminate form. OP does seem to believe that if the limit doesn't exist then somehow that has something to do with indeterminate forms.

Answer (score 0):

if $y = x ^{1/x}$ then $\log y = \log x /x$. Meaning that your limit is $\exp( \lim _{x\to 0} \log x / x)$ which indeed is $\pm \infty/0$ indeterminate.

Comment: by the way limit DNE as commentors above pointed out the function is not defined for $x < 0$.

Comment: No, it is of the form $-\infty/0,$ or $-\infty\cdot\infty.$

Comment: There is definition of limit which says limit exists in this case ($S=(0;+\infty)$): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#More_general_subsets

Answer (score 0):

In general for $f(x)>0$

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow x_0} \left(f(x)\right)^{g(x)}$$

with $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow x_0} g(x)=\infty$ is not an indeterminate form because

$$\left(f(x)\right)^{g(x)} =e^{g(x)\log (f(x))} \to e^{-\infty}=0$$

As noticed, in this particular case, the limit is well defined only for $x>0$ that is

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^+} e^{\frac{\log x}x}=0$$
since $\frac{\log x}x =\frac1x \cdot \log x \to -\infty $.

Refer also to

- [Is $0^\infty$ indeterminate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520795/505767)
- [How to prove that a form like $0^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form? What makes a form indeterminate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3938452/505767)